# apache RewriteRule prefix with wwwwww instead of www

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Using this for example:

```
RewriteEngine On  
Rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.hslab\.nl
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.hslab.nl/$1 [R=301,L]
```

It will add the `www` part to the url if it is not there.
Why can it not be something other then `www`, for example `wwwwwww`?
When I do that I get a 404.

Comment: Thanks for showing your htaccess rule file in your question, could you please do let us know more clearly what you are looking for here? because your rule looks correct to me with respect to adding www to urls, thank you.

Comment: I would like `wwwwww` instead of `www` but then it breaks.

Comment: Do you have `wwwwww` configured in `VirtualHost`?

Comment: @anubhavaI I can't find any access to change that.

Comment: You do need to access `VirtualHost` config to set it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your shown samples, could you please try following. Please make sure you clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
##Rule when www is present in URL so add only www to url.
Rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www)\.hslab\.nl
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%1.hslab.nl%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]

##Rule when www is NOT present in URL, hence add wwwwww to url as per OP
Rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.hslab\.nl
RewriteRule ^ http://wwwwww.hslab.nl%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```

Comment: For those interested, it works but I do get `Apache is functioning normally ` instead of the site.